# Does turning off output make aircrack-ng work faster?

Tags: password-cracking, aircrack-ng

I know that preventing output on the console or in anyway makes the program run much faster. Displaying the output is a long process to complete.

But I wonder if using `-q` option in aircrack-ng, which basically skips the output, would make a significant difference? I'm doubtful because aircrack-ng doesn't display Master Key, Transient Key and EAPOL HMAC for all the keys in the dictionary.

Comment: What is the stopwatch telling you?

Comment: Seems like a very easy thing to test

Comment: @eckes : I thought someone must have already tested it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried aircrack-ng on a dictionary with 2,000,000 keys and none of these keys is the correct password. So aircrack-ng had to go through all of those 2,000,000 passwords. Handshake was WPA encrypted, aircrack version was "Aircrack-ng 1.2 rc4". I ran this test on a Core i5 4th Gen machine with 4 gigs DDR3 ram and here's the result:

```
Normal Mode (With Output)   : 1281.495 seconds
Quiet Mode (Without Output) : 1264.578 seconds
```

The time noted is not the system/CPU time of the process but instead it's wall clock time (i.e. all the elapsed time including time slices used by other processes).

So yes, preventing the output does make a difference but it's not as much as I expected. Maybe it's because aircrack-ng doesn't create output for all the keys tested.